# How to have button clone parent div onto body

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to have a button that, when clicked, will clone the parent of the buttons parent and append to the body:

```html
<div class="userposts">
    <p class="postusername">Posted by $postuser</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function click() {
            var div = this.parentElement.parentElement;
            var clone = div.cloneNode(true);

            document.body.appendChild(clone);

        }
    </script>
    <h2 class="posttitle"><button onclick="click()" type="button">$title<button></a></h2>
```

This is what I have so far but It doesn't append anything nor does it leave any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the click() function is a reserved name in JavaScript, try to rename it.

Comment: [`click` is not a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords). It is, however, a property of the button DOM element. So rather than calling the `click` function defined by the OP, this attribute is calling the [`click` function defined by the button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you put a `</a>`?

And this is how:

```js
function clone(e) {
  document.querySelector("body").append(e.parentNode.cloneNode(true))
}
```

```html
<body>
<h3>Hello World <button type="button" onclick="clone(this)">[clone]</button></h3>
</body>
```

1. Use `onclik` attribute
2. Put `this` on function like `onclick="clone(this)"`
3. Get parent node `e.parentNode`
4. Clone with `cloneNode(true)`

Bye!

Comment: Whoops, </a> was left by mistake. I needed to change the function name but using this as parameters was needed as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your `click` function was not called is because the JavaScript code in your attribute is executed in a context where the element's attributes are copied into the context of the attribute's JavaScript code. So your `click` function was hidden behind the [element's `click` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

See MDN's [DOM onevent handlers: HTML onevent attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#HTML_onevent_attributes)

You can reproduce this effect with any property/method/etc. of the button DOM element.

For example, the following button, when clicked, will cause an error: `Uncaught TypeError: innerHTML is not a function`

```html
<script>
    function innerHTML(el) {
        console.log(el.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<button onclick="innerHTML(this)">Click Me</button>
```

Note that this effect only applies to the JavaScript within the attribute string. If we use a function name that doesn't overlap with a DOM element attribute, then we can safely avoid this sort of error:

```html
<script>
    function handleClick(el) {
        // We can safely call the innerHTML function from within this function
        innerHTML(el);
    }
    function innerHTML(el) {
        console.log(el.innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<button onclick="handleClick(this)">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

better to leave clean html

```
<h3 class="toClone">Some title <button type="button">[toClone]</button></h3>
```

and use **onclick** in JS function

```
   let butonClone = document.querySelector('button')
   let myBody = document.querySelector('body')
   let toClone = document.querySelector('.toClone')

   butonClone.onclick = function clone() {
        myBody.append(toClone.parentNode.cloneNode(true))
   }
```